# Explanation for "them's" as in "them's the rules"

Tags: meaning, slang, verb-agreement, contractions, them-is

Recently someone said to me:

> Them's the rules

I thought he had the sentence wrong, but as it turns out it is slang. I am learning English as a second language and I would really appreciate if someone could explain what it means and in which context I am allowed to use it.

Comment: ["Them's the rules", "them's the breaks", "them's the facts", "them's the orders",](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=them%27s+the+rules%2Cthem%27s+the+breaks%2Cthem%27s+the+orders%2Cthem%27s+the+facts&year_start=1950&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=) ... they all mean that them's the way them is, and nobody can do anything about it.

Comment: It means, simply, "Those are the rules".  Not strictly "legal" grammar, but idiomatic as a casual, slightly jocular (or cynical) statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an idiom used by particular groups of English speakers (Southern Americans, Brooklynites, for example) in colloquial speech. It means, *those are the rules*. If you see it in printed form, it will likely be in dialogue spoken by a person who uses a distinct dialect. Here are some examples of its use over the years. You'll see that each example contains a heavy dose of other dialectical pronunciations and informal ungrammatical constructions.

From a magazine called [Old Guard](http://books.google.es/books?id=k7ITAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA298&dq=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H67JUJLsNcazhAf42YGICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&f=false), published in the 1860s in New York City:

> "If the tin's here empty when I comes back, I takes it away. If the wittals is here, why I takes them away. *Them's the rules*."

From a literary magazine called [The Writer](http://books.google.es/books?id=JiU5AAAAMAAJ&q=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&dq=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_7DJUKL_A5KwhAejwIFI&redir_esc=y) published in 1927:

> Wot you a-doin' of? Writin' up yer diry? Eat an' walk--*them's the rules* 'ere. They's others writin'."

From a book called *[From the Brooklyn Side](http://books.google.es/books?id=b4V1SeFF0yAC&pg=PA337&dq=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=orHJULuFI9KThgfvl4GIAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&f=false)* published in 2000:

> "*Them's the rules*, Dominick. We either live by 'em or we die by 'em. But we ain't gonna break 'em for nobody."

---

Occasionally, the expression will be used in a jokey manner, as @Barrie England points out, by someone who speaks proper English to express the irony of the *rules*. As if those rules have been created by an uneducated person who would say "them's the rules" and not "those are the rules."

For example, in this passage from a book called [Resurrection Day](http://books.google.es/books?id=7rxXNWIERBEC&q=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&dq=%22them%27s%20the%20rules%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=orHJULuFI9KThgfvl4GIAw&redir_esc=y) published in 2000:

> "Not my problem. *Them's the rules*, and that's why I'm about to pull the pin and get out of this rotten city on full pension."

---

Because it is an ungrammatical idiom, it is best used either humorously or ironically unless it is in the written dialogue of a character who speaks in that dialect, and then it can be used literally (meaning *those are the rules*) and to your heart's content.

Comment: Slight nitpick on a good answer: it is grammatical in some varieties of English, though not in any standard English that I am aware of.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't slang. Slang is mostly to do with vocabulary rather than grammar. In some nonstandard dialects of English, *is* (or *'s*) is used in persons other than the third person singular, and this is an example. Actually, it is probably being used in this case in a jokey sort of way, just as *ain't* often is. As a foreign learner, you would be wise to avoid it in your own speech.

**EDIT:** I omitted to say that *them* is used in some nonstandard dialects for standard *those*, both as a demonstrative pronoun and as a demonstrative determiner.

Answer (score 3):

In my village dialect, not far from Newcastle, UK "them's" is used as a short form of "they are" or "those are". Not grammatically correct but understood but all locals. Foreign language students would do well to avoid using it.

Comment: is it? how interesting I am from near York, and it would only ever be used in jest round here.

Answer (score -2):

“It seems so unreal and yet it’s real, sorry kiddo.” this reads as very detached, like she's telling tullia to get over. "Sorry, them's the breaks."

Above, a line of a critique I got for my short story. I wouldn't know how to use it.

And why are English natives so nasty to non-natives? It's frustrating!

Sarcastic?

Comment: Hello, Gwendolin. There is a list of regulations at the Help Center, which include not asking questions in 'answers', flagging questions asking 'Why are X  so lousy?', and suggesting that ELL is often a better site for non-natives to ask many questions on. I don't wish to break the rules, so I have to downvote.

Comment: No problem. Was a question posted in answers. I will post questions in the appropriate section, and answers as well.  Thank you